# How to normalize the default date format for a column in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

Will start of by saying I am not the most experienced with Python, I am still learning. For the current project that I am working on, I have to load a CSV file into a Python, in which I created a Pandas DataFrame out of. The objective is to return the data types of each column, specifically ones with different date formats. I created a small sample CSV file to test whether it can identify the proper data types.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from tabulate import tabulate
    from datetime import datetime

    #Read the CSV file into Pandas DataFrame
    df= pd.DataFrame.from_csv("/Users/rohinmahesh/Documents/Example_CSV1.csv")

    #Create a list of column names (Insert row number column at beginning later)
    lst = list(df.columns.values)


    #Identify column data type

    print(df.dtypes)
```

The CSV file looks as following:
[CSV File:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHRju.png)

The problem I am facing is that when I am calling the print statement, the "Dates" column and the "Location" column are both returning as objects. For the project, I need the "Location" column to be identified as a String, and the "Dates" column to be identified as a Date (or DateTime in Python?) which I have an understanding could possibly be done by normalizing a date format?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thank you for the response back! I am getting an error that says "Only booleans, lists, and dictionaries are accepted for the 'parse_dates' parameter." Should I use from_csv instead?

Comment: Do you use  `parse_dates=['Date']` in read_csv ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need `parse_dates` parameter in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""Date
1-Mar-16
13-1-2015
5/2/16"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), parse_dates=['Date'])
print (df)
        date
0 2016-03-01
1 2015-01-13
2 2016-05-02

print (df.Date.dtypes)
datetime64[ns]
```

But if there are some non standard values use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with parameter `errors='coerce'` for replace them to `NaT` (`NaN` for datetimes):

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""Date
date20150109
1-Mar-16
13-1-2015
5/2/16"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp))
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce')
print (df)
        Date
0        NaT
1 2016-03-01
2 2015-01-13
3 2016-05-02


print (df.Date.dtypes)
datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you possibly explain what the errors='coerce' is doing exactly? What does that mean/indicate?

Comment: to_datetime with it return  no error for values which cannot be parsed to datetime. So all these values are converted to NaT. Is it more clear?